# Connecting to private IP's in Ubuntu 14.04 with Microsoft VPN

Tags: networking, windows, vpn, dns, ip

I have an installation of Ubuntu 14.04 configured with a VPN connection. I followed [this article](http://labnotes.decampo.org/2012/12/ubuntu-1210-connect-to-microsoft-vpn.html) which seemed to pertain to Ubuntu 12.10 but the instructions seemed to apply for the new version as well.

When I connect to the VPN (which does seem to connect successfully), I am unable to access any internal resources using either IP address or DNS name. However, if I go to google.com, I am redirected to the regional Google site for that connection (google.no).

I have this VPN set up and working well in Windows, so perhaps there is some way to recreate the following setup in Ubuntu 14.04?

This is a section of the command `ipconfig /all` in Windows 8:

```
PPP adapter (my VPN name):

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : (my VPN name)
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.79(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.91
                                    192.168.0.1
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

This is the output from `netstat -rn`:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlan0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlan0
192.168.0.103   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 ppp0
(vpn gateway)   192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 wlan0
(vpn gateway)   192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 wlan0
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your `netstat -rn`

Comment: Don't see anything in the routing table that would say to forward private VPN traffic through VPN

Comment: How could I configure that setting?

Comment: The last two lines seem to indicate that there is some sort of route. Where it says (vpn gateway), this is the public IP of the VPN. I see this entry on my Windows machine also.

Answer (score 0):

VPN server should push a route to local subnet through VPN you can do `netstat -rn` on your working windows box to confirm that it gets the route in there. So need to troubleshoot why VPN doesn't push it out. You can also add a route yourself once you're connected to the VPN `route add -net NETWORK netmask NETMASK gw VPNGATEWAY` where NETWORK/NETMASK is for **"internal resources"**

Comment: Thanks. I can see many entries on the Windows machine when I run that command. Is there not some way that Ubuntu can retrieve these settings automatically as per the Windows machine? It is just the standard Microsoft PPTP VPN.

Comment: Did you read the part from your link where it talks about **Click the Routes button.
Check Use this connection only for resources on its network
Add a route: ** ? Add the resources you want to get to through vpn that way